# Trigger: Delete Child Cloned Opportunities If Parent Opportunity is deleted

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger, clone

I have to implement a functionality to delete all child cloned opportunity if parent opportunity is deleted.

Details:

1. There is a self lookup on Opportunity.
2. Cloned opportunity is clone of opportunity with different Id.

Clone functionality Code:
//Clone the Opportunity

```
        Opportunity opportunityCloneRecord = opportunityRecord.clone(false, true, false, false); 
        opportunityCloneRecord.AccountId = AccountId; 
        opportunityCloneRecord.Name = 'Clone-' + opportunityRecord.Name;
        opportunityCloneRecord.StageName = opportunityRecord.StageName; 
        opportunityCloneRecord.CloseDate = opportunityRecord.CloseDate; 
        opportunityCloneRecord.ParentOpportunityId__c = recordId; //Relate cloned Opportunity to Parent Opportunity Id 
        opportunityCloneRecord.Child_Cloned_Opportunity__c = true; 
        opportunityCloneRecord.Pricebook2Id = opportunityRecord.Pricebook2Id;
```

3. When child cloned opportunity is created checkbox field is checked true.

I have written a trigger but it's not working.

Trigger:

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (Before delete) {

if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete){
        OpportunityTriggerHandler.deleteCloneOpportunities(Trigger.old); 
    }

}
```

OpportunityTriggerHandler:

```
public static void deleteCloneOpportunities(List<Opportunity> oldOpportunityList){
       
        Set<id> opportunityIdSet = new Set<id>();
        for(Opportunity oppObj : oldOpportunityList){
            if(oppObj.ParentOpportunityId__c!=null)
                opportunityIdSet.add(oppObj.id);
          
        }
        
        List<Opportunity> childClonedOpportunities = new list<Opportunity>([select id from Opportunity where ParentOpportunityId__c in : opportunityIdSet]);
        
        if(childClonedOpportunities!=null && !childClonedOpportunities.isEmpty()){
            delete childClonedOpportunities;
        }
        
    }
```

Could you please suggest how could I modify my trigger to delete cloned opportunities if Parent Opportunity is deleted.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Opp that is being deleted would not have the "ParentOpportunityId__c" set - you want to simply capture all of the Ids of the Opps being deleted.

Change line:

```
if(oppObj.ParentOpportunityId__c!=null) opportunityIdSet.add(oppObj.id);
```

to simply be:

```
opportunityIdSet.add(oppObj.id);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried with the same approach you suggested and it worked. Thank you so much for your time.